# why does my array SC is the same with SN?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static int[] tranzitie(int[] stare, int x, int y) {
    stare[x] = y;
    return stare;
}

int[] SC = {3,1,1,1};
int[] SN = {3,1,1,1};                             

SN = tranzitie(SC, x, y);
```

//when i do this, i want to change only SN
//but in my case SN = SC

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Both arrays have the same element values. What's the problem?

Comment: yes, but after i do SN = tranzitie(SC, 2, 3); (for example) SN wil become{3,1,3,1}, and i want SC to remain {3,1,1,1} ,but it is same as SN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the original array, then you must make a *defensive copy* and work on that copy instead, for example:

```
public static int[] tranzitie(int[] stare, int x, int y) {
    int[] copy = stare.clone();
    copy[x] = y;
    return copy;
}
```

See this [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/641955) which explains in detail how method parameters are passed in Java.

Comment: its correct if i do int[] copy = (int[]) stare.clone();?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to cast with `(int[])`, the example I gave should work as it is.

Comment: it say "cannot convert from object to int[]"

Answer (score 0):

In Java, arrays are objects, and when you assign an `int[]` variable or pass one as a parameter, you're actually assigning or passing a *reference* to the array object.

Thus, in this call:

```
SN = tranzitie(SC, x, y);
```

`tranzitie` gets a *reference* to the `SC` array, not a copy of it.  The `stare` parameter will be referring to the same array.  Thus, when the method says

```
stare[x] = y;
```

**it actually modifies** `SC`---not a *copy* of `SC`, but the actual array itself.

When the method says `return stare`, since `stare` is a reference to the SC array object, the method will return that reference.  Then you assign `SN` to that.  The result will be that `SN` and `SC` are now references to the same array.  The array that you created earlier:

```
int[] SN = {3,1,1,1};
```

will no longer be accessible (unless you stored the reference somewhere else).

If this is not what you want, then you have to handle your arrays carefully; the `CopyOf` and `CopyOfRange` methods in [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) are helpful in making copies of arrays or parts of arrays.